# Design pattern to encapsulate override and static decorations

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a class that adds behaviour to a button but I would like to encapsulate the added behaviour so that I can also add it to other derivatives of ButtonBase.  The behaviour manages additions to the logical tree so that I can make xaml-composable, multi target commands.

## Custom Control

```
public class MultiCommandButton : Button
{

    #region Command

    public Collection<object> _logicalChildren { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get
        {
            if(_logicalChildren == null) return base.LogicalChildren;
            return this._logicalChildren.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public static void CommandChangedCallback (DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var multitarget = e.NewValue as MultiTargetCommand;
        if (multitarget == null) return;

        var b = d as MultiCommandButton;
        if (b == null) return;

        _changeLogicalMultiTargetCommand(b, e.OldValue, e.NewValue);

        if (e.OldValue == null) return;
        b.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);
    }

    public static void _changeLogicalMultiTargetCommand (MultiCommandButton b, 
        object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var children = b._logicalChildren;
        if (children != null && oldValue is MultiTargetCommand)
        {
            if (children.Contains(oldValue))
            {
                children.Remove(oldValue);
                b.RemoveLogicalChild(oldValue);

                children.Add(newValue);
                b.AddLogicalChild(newValue);

                return;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one MultiCommand can be set");
        }

        var baseChildren = b.LogicalChildren;
        object content = null;
        if (baseChildren != null && baseChildren.MoveNext())
        {
            content = baseChildren.Current;
        }

        b._logicalChildren = new Collection<object>();
        if (content != null)
            b._logicalChildren.Add(content);

        b._logicalChildren.Add(newValue);

        b.AddLogicalChild(newValue);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    static MultiCommandButton()
    {
        CommandProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MultiCommandButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CommandChangedCallback));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## Example View

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Targets">

    <Button x:Name="Button1">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
            <ctb:OutputToggleEnabledBind />
        </Button.CommandBindings>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="Button2">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
            <ctb:OutputToggleEnabledBind />
        </Button.CommandBindings>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="Button3">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
            <ctb:OutputToggleEnabledBind />
        </Button.CommandBindings>
    </Button>

</StackPanel>

<ctb:MultiCommandButton x:Name="MultiEnable"
                        CommandParameter="Multi Target">

    ^^^Multi Target Toggle Enabled^^^

    <ctb:MultiCommandButton.Command>
        <ctb:MultiTargetCommand
            Command="{x:Static ctb:MultiCommands.OutputToggleEnabled}">
            <ctb:CommandTarget Target="{Binding ElementName=Button1}" />
            <ctb:CommandTarget Target="{Binding ElementName=Button2}" />
        </ctb:MultiTargetCommand>
    </ctb:MultiCommandButton.Command>

</ctb:MultiCommandButton>
```

## What I tried

I tried to achieve this in three ways...

1. Move the common, static elements to a static service class
2. Create an interface to outline the instance requirements
3. Convert the static methods to instance methods and use an interface

The other option, that I am trying to avoid is to simply boilerplate the members into derived classes.

### Static Service Class

I made some of the methods static in the hope that I could move them to a static service class.  The problem I have with this is that the static methods reference protected internal properties on a base class (e.g. `RemoveLogicalChild` from `FrameworkElement`), so the static methods are lexically bound to my derived class by virtue of their access specifiers.  Therefore, I can't move these methods to a service class without exposing these properties, with relay properties on the derived class.  This seems like a code smell.

### Create an Interface

I don't know if there is any approach, analogous to an Interface, that can be applied to static members so, since I can't move the static members to a service class, I can't use an interface.  I also have one property that is an override and I thought this would also be a problem, but it seems ok to use the `new` keyword: although this feels like a risk for the particular application as WPF may access the base property and ignore the new one (I can actually see this difference in WPF inspector).

### Convert the static members to instance ones and use an interface

This works, but creates unnecessary instance versions of the methods that could be static and leaves me with a risk that the virtual, FrameworkElement property that I override, may be subverted because I had to use the new keyword instead.

## Question

What is the cleanest, driest way to do this?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can create extension methods for an interface. It would work out to be the same as the 'service' class but would be a bit more idiomatic. You would have to expose the methods and getters for the protected properties through the interface and explicitly implement them.

Comment: Good guidance though @KeithPayne, that's another dimension I forgot to consider and idiomatic is also a good thing. I'll explore that.